# How to check whether check box is selected or not in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I created one panel. I added one checkbox in that panel. I need to check whether that checkbox selected or not from outside function. Please any one help me....

```
this.currentManagerPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    border: false,
    width: 550,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        name: 'isNewEmployee',
        height: 20,
        boxLabel: 'Is New Employee',
        inputValue: ''
    }]
});
```

Comment: I got the answer. I changed instead of name property i provided id property and then i can read the value using Ext.getCmp("isNewEmployee").checked; Now it will return checkbox selected or not..

Answer (score 3):

```
using Ext.getCmp("isNewEmployee").checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your `controller.js` :

```
var form = win.down('form');                        
var allFields =  form.getForm().getFieldValues();
var value = form.getForm().findField('isNewEmployee').getValue();
// This will return True or False
```